# selenium.waitForPageToLoad doesn't seem to be waiting

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm updating a Selenium program I wrote a while back and part of it has stopped working. I want to go through a whole series of links on a page, click on each, making sure that some expected text is present. But sometimes a log-in page (https://library.med.nyu.edu/sso/ezproxy_form.php) appears before the desired page, in which case I need to log in before checking the page. <strike>The problem is, no matter what string I put in to check whether I've landed on the log in page, Selenium concludes it's not present and skips logging in, obviously causing everything else to fail.</strike> See below--I'm not sure that was actually the problem. It seems to be instead that it's rushing through the "if we need to sign in" code without actually signing in, then obviously failing the main part of the test because it's not on the right page.

Here's the code--does anyone see my mistake?

```
       for (int i = 0; i < Resources.size(); i++) {
        try {
                        selenium.open("/");
                        selenium.click("link=" + Resources.get(i).link);
                        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("100000");
                        if (selenium.isTextPresent("Please sign in to access NYUHSL e-resources")) {
                            selenium.type("sso_user", kid);
                            selenium.type("sso_pass", password);
                            selenium.click("name=SignIn");
                            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("100000");
                        }

                        if (!selenium.isTextPresent(Resources.get(i).text)) {
                            outfile.println(Resources.get(i).name + " failed");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        outfile.println(Resources.get(i).name + " could not be found--link removed?");
                    }
       }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Does the login page have a page title? If yes, try validating the page title using **selenium.getTitle()** method to check if you are headed to login page. If not, proceed clicking on the link without logging in.

I think page title validation can help resolve this issue

Comment: Thank you. I've spent some more time working on this and added the getTitle() function. Unfortunately, that didn't help. It seems like there is something wrong with the timing, even though I increased both waits to 400000(!) and moved the second wait inside the first if statement. It seems like the program is chaotically hurtling through the clicks without waiting. It starts looking for Resources.get(i).name before the log-in page has even loaded, decides it isn't there, and goes straight back to re-opening "/". It doesn't seem to be respecting the wait at all!

Comment: That's strange. Is it timing out? What is the exact error message? You could use e.printstacktrace() in the catch block to get the detailed exception for debugging the issue

Comment: I don't think it's timing out. Let's say that I was testing whether a link to the NYTimes worked, and the text it's looking for is "© 2011 The New York Times Company" in the footer. What I see in the log window in Firefox as this is running is that it gets to my proxy login page and within fractions of a second has run through and looked for "© 2011 The New York Times Company", failed because it's on the login page still, and it starts the loop over, going back to my homepage and trying to test the next link.

Comment: At first I thought this was because it wasn't recognizing the login page, but I made the getTitle change and it does seem to be recognizing it. Just not actually logging in or waiting. I've checked the names of the form elements a dozen times... I don't get an error message, it just keeps blowing through my tests without giving the right results!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting:

```
selenium.setSpeed("1000");
```

Right after the selenium.open this will inject 1 second delay (1000ms) between selenium commands. You should make it a standard practice to add this, especially if you're not running headless browsers.

Also you might consider using, since you know the url you are expecting to be on if on the login page, the selenium command getLocation. This will return the absolute URL of the current page. Might be more effective than trying to look for elements that can change at any time within the page.

So to use getLocation in your code above:

```
if (selenium.getLocation() == "your reference url"){
do your login stuff here
}
```

Again this is just a sample to illustrate what I'm saying. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks! I've found out more about this problem (side project I don't often have time to work on) and it turns out that I misdiagnosed it--I think I should post a new question because it's rather different--it's doing page redirects so quickly that I couldn't "see" them.